# Profiling stock Ubuntu kernel with sysprof: how?

Tags: kernel, debugging

There are various system-wide debug tools (sysprof, oprofile, systemtap) that need debug symbols.  Getting debug symbols for userspace applications is easy: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash

The ddebs repository also contains `linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym` packages, but even if I install it, sysprof continues to show me unhelpful "in kernel" without detailed information.  Where can I get debug symbols that sysprof can use?

The systemtap package has a Suggests: linux-debug-2.6.  Apt-cache search fails to find anything called linux-debug-2.6.  Is it available somewhere?  Or is this an unproductive dead-end?

Incidentally, oprofile can use the debug symbols from the above-mentioned dbgsym package, but not out of the box -- it wants
`/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/vmlinux`, and I have to tell it to use use `/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-$(uname -r)-generic`.  But oprofile lacks a nice GUI, so I'd prefer sysprof.

So, how can I convince sysprof to show me what's happening in the kernel?

Comment: Can sysprof even do that?  The website claims "Detailed, accurate, profiling of the entire Linux system, including both the *kernel* and *all userspace application*", but none of the example screenshots show any in-kernel symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, I was mistaken and sysprof doesn't actually provide any level of detail beyond "in kernel".  Here's sysprof-1.0.12/process.c, lines 350 through 355:

```
    if (address == 0x1)
    {
        kernel.name = "in kernel";
        kernel.address = 0x0001337;
        return &kernel;
    }
```